# XML Type in oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have the following query in SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Templates_LoadXML_AddOthers](
@XMLString varchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ERRMessage varchar(max)=''
DECLARE @SPName varchar(100) = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
DECLARE @RowCount int=0

declare @XML as xml


SELECT @XML = TRY_CAST(@XMLString as xml)
IF (@XML Is Not Null) 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MSG varchar(100) ='XML Not Null'
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO tblTemplates_Load_OtherObjects_Raw(OtherObjectsField,[Value])
        ----1
        SELECT  
           q.col.value('fld[1]', 'varchar(50)'),  
           q.col.value('val[1]', 'varchar(100)')
        FROM   @xml.nodes('//TPL') q(col) 
        ----2 
        SELECT @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @ERRMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() 
    END CATCH
END

ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @ERRMessage='Failed to convert XMLString to xml data type.'
END

IF (@ERRMessage<>'')
BEGIN
    EXEC spInsertAppLog @LogEntry=@ERRMessage, @CodeSource=@SPName
    RAISERROR (@ERRMessage, 16, 1 )
    RETURN
END

SELECT @RowCount
END
```

How can the part in between 1 and 2 which i have marked in the code be written in oracle.
I have read articles on extract method in oracle but not able to comprehend.
*Can anybody throw some light on this.*

Comment: please edit the question, and show the example XML, and expected output.  Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `XMLTABLE`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tblTemplates_Load_Other_Raw(
  OtherObjectsField VARCHAR2(50),
  Value             VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertAppLog( LogEntry IN VARCHAR2, CodeSource IN VARCHAR2 )
AS
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( CodeSource || ' - ' || LogEntry );
END;
/
```

**Procedure**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Templ_LoadXML_AddOthers(
  i_XMLString IN  VARCHAR2,
  o_ROWCOUNT  OUT NUMBER
)
AS
  c_proc_name CONSTANT VARCHAR2(30)   := 'usp_Templ_LoadXML_AddOthers';
  p_xml                XMLTYPE        := NULL;
  p_message            VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    p_xml := XMLType( i_XMLString );
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      p_xml := NULL;
  END;

  IF p_xml IS NULL THEN
    p_message := 'Failed to convert XMLString to xml data type.';
    spInsertAppLog( LogEntry => p_message, CodeSource => c_proc_name );
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20000, p_message );
  END IF;

  INSERT INTO tblTemplates_Load_Other_Raw( OtherObjectsField, Value )
  SELECT fld, val
  FROM   XMLTABLE(
           '//TPL'
           PASSING p_xml
           COLUMNS fld VARCHAR2(50)  PATH 'fld[1]',
                   val VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'val[1]'
         );
  o_RowCount := SQL%RowCount;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    p_message := SQLERRM;
    spInsertAppLog( LogEntry => p_message, CodeSource => c_proc_name );
    RAISE;
END;
/
```

**Calling the procedure**:

```
DECLARE
  p_rows NUMBER(4,0);
BEGIN
  usp_Templ_LoadXML_AddOthers(
    '<root>
      <TPL>
        <fld>f1</fld><val>v1</val>
      </TPL>
      <TPL>
        <fld>f2.1</fld><val>v2.1</val>
        <fld>f2.2</fld><val>v2.2</val>
      </TPL>
    </root>',
    p_rows
  );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( p_rows );
END;
/
```

**Output**:

```
dbms_output:
2
```

**Table contents**:

```
SELECT * FROM tblTemplates_Load_Other_Raw;
```

```
OTHEROBJECTSFIELD | VALUE
:---------------- | :----
f1                | v1   
f2.1              | v2.1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9c761056d99721019be101b2f34a0f69)*

Comment: Superb.Many Thanks for putting in so much of effort.